# Get Computer Names of a Lan in C#

Tags: c#, lan, computer-name

I want to create a chat application in which there is a `ComboBx`. I want to fill it with all the computer names in a network. How can I accomplish this in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option for discovering other computers in a LAN running the same application is probably **mDNS**.

Have a look at the [Bonjour SDK for Windows](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/) which comes with a COM library usable from C# and sample code.